# How to do early stopping in Flux.jl

Tags: julia, flux.jl

Using Flux.jl, is there a way I can avoid overfitting by implementing some sort of early stopping functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flux.jl provides a built in `Flux.early_stopping` function which can be used as follows:

```
julia> loss = let l = 0
         () -> l += 1
       end; # pseudo loss function that returns increasing values

julia> es = Flux.early_stopping(loss, 3);

julia> Flux.@epochs 30 begin
         es() && break
       end

[ Info: Epoch 1
```

you can read more about this here: https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/utilities/#Flux.early_stopping for further details on how to implement early stopping in Flux.